# Can I use Vuetify through NPM without touching WebPack in a lagacy project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a legacy project with a very complex WebPack config.

Luckily, I can still use the latest version of NPM.

Now, I want to install Vuetify in my project, I can do this

`npm install vuetify`

However, I thought this will be the end, and I can start wrapping my root with `v-app`, but there is more config!

Please see: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/

`npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D`

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
            fiber: require('fibers'),
            indentedSyntax: true // optional
          },
          // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
            sassOptions: {
              fiber: require('fibers'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I can't touch my WebPack right now, it's too complex.

How can I use Vuetify through NPM without touching WebPack in my lagacy project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, scroll down and you'll see that you can use the [CDN version](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#cdn-usage).

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
  </script>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: But I still want to use it through NPM, is it possible?